# Fragment Transaction using tabbed Fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am creating tabbed fragments. The Main Activity is called `media_main`, as it is an activity I believe fragment transaction wont work- From this MainActivity there comes 3 tabbed fragments.

I need to know how to get to these through my Navigation Drawer? Do I FragmentTransaction to my Main Activity - is this even possible? or Am I stuck with just using a normal intent?

This is what I have:

```
case R.id.nav_media:
           fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, media_main());
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
           getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Media");
           item.setCheckable(true);
           drawerLayout.closeDrawers();               
           break;
```

Comment: your question is not at all clear. what do you mean by "as it is an activity I believe fragment transaction wont work".. why not ?

Comment: Do I FragmentTransaction to my Main Activity - is this even possible?
Yes, it is possible.

Comment: How can I do this FragmentTransaction to MainActivity when it is an activity? Does it not have to be a fragment to use fragment transaction?